# Importing and calling the function on the same line in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

A module in NodeJS could be required as follows, where I import and call the required function on the same line.

```
require('./my-module')({
    mysql: sequelizeO,
    logger: logger,
    sqlModel: sequelizeModels,
    sqlModelAlias: alias,
});
```

How could I do the same in typescript? In typescript I have been doing as follows:

```
import MyModule from './my-module';

MyModule({
    mysql: sequelizeO,
    logger: logger,
    sqlModel: sequelizeModels,
    sqlModelAlias: alias,
})
```

So it became a two-line code, whereas in NodeJS I able to require and call the function on the same line. How could I do the same in typescript?

Comment: You can try this. 

import('./my-module').then(module => module({
    mysql: sequelizeO,
    logger: logger,
    sqlModel: sequelizeModels,
    sqlModelAlias: alias,
}))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. In `NodeJS`, `require` returns something, but in TypeScript, `import` is an statement, not a function, and statements do not have a value, so you can't 'invoke' them. You'll have to keep doing it like you do right now.